# How can I avoid warnings about unused variables?

Tags: vimscript

I have some code in my `~/.vimrc` that (simplified) looks like this:

```
function! SomeAppendFunction()
    let failed = append(0, ["Some header text"])
endfunction
command SomeAppendFunction :call SomeAppendFunction()
```

The intent is to provide a command that prepends some fixed text to any file I wish. I don't really care too much about handling errors from the `append()` function.

When I run [Syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic) over this, which uses [vimlint](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/wiki/VimL%3A---vimlint) to check it, it quite rightly warns that I'm not using the return variable `failed`:

```
/Users/xyz/.vimrc|255 col 9 warning| [EVL102] unused variable `l:failed`
```

However, if I remove the `let failed =` from the line inside the function, so it looks like this:

```
function! SomeAppendFunction()
    append(0, ["Some header text"])
endfunction
command SomeAppendFunction :call SomeAppendFunction()
```

... I instead now see: ...

```
line  301:
E126: Missing :endfunction
```

... when I start vim.

How can I avoid the warning about the unused variable, but also have a syntactically correct function?

Comment: There are a few ways to do it: (1) `call append(...)`; (2) put `" @vimlint(EVL102, 1, l:failed)` and `" @vimlint(EVL102, 0, l:failed)` around your function; (3) `let g:syntastic_vimlint_options = { 'EVL102': 1 }`; (4) use `g:syntastic_quiet_messages`; (5) use `g:syntastic_vim_vimlint_quiet_messages`.

Comment: @lcd047, ok, thanks. All but (1) are suppressing the warning in vimlint, not fixing the root cause. So I'm going to accept Christian's answer. But good tips if there's a slightly different vimlint issue in future.

Comment: The root cause is you not checking for errors.  None of the above fixes that, but all of them answer your question as you asked it: "avoid the warning about the unused variable, but also have a syntactically correct function". _shrug_

Comment: @lcd047 fair point :) Anyway, thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`append()` is a function and no command. As such, it must be called using the `:call` command. So use `:call append()`. Second, if you want to ignore errors, you can wrap the whole command into a `try...catch...endtry` statement like this:

```
try
   call append()   " could fail for whatever reason
catch
   " no-op
endtry
```

Comment: Perfect, using `call` works. I'm not interested in swallowing any errors either (it's not something worth writing error-handling for, but I'm happy for the error to bubble up - if you see what it's doing, it's very unlikely to fail anyway :). Thanks.